# Intuition behind the elements of $\mathbb{Z}D_4$ group ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, soft-question, intuition

I have been reading Dummit and Foote, and according to it if $R$ is a commutative ring with multiplicative identity $1$, and $G$ is a finite group (say of order $n$), then the group ring $RG$ is defined as the set of all formal sums:
$$a_1g_1+a_2g_2+\ldots+a_ng_n\ \ \ \ \text{where }g_i\in G,\ a_i\in R\ \forall\ i\in \{1,\ 2, \ldots,\ n\}$$

Now define $G=D_4$ and $R=\mathbb{Z}$ to form the group ring $\mathbb{Z}D_4$.

We know that $D_4=\langle r,\ s\mid r^4=s^2=1,\ rs=sr^{-1}\rangle $ where $r$ corresponds to the action of rotating a square on the axis passing through its center by $\pi/2$ radians, and $s$ corresponds to the action of reflecting a square (or kind of like flipping the square) through the axis passing through its center and middle of the side. So the group $D_4$ and its elements can be understood intuitively, like $r^2s$ means rotating the square by $\pi$ radians and flipping it, etc.

But now as the group ring $\mathbb{Z}D_4$ is formed, elements such as $r^3-2r^2s+3s-r$ emerge as well.

My question is, just as we interpreted elements of $D_4$ (or as a matter of fact, any dihedral group) as consecutive actions of rotating and flipping a square (or other regular polygon in case of other dihedral groups), how do we intuitively interpret the elements of $\mathbb{Z}D_4$?

***THANK YOU***

Comment: One interesting point:   the group of units of the group ring contains a copy of the original group.   In this case $D_4$.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}$ is the translation group of the integers, so we can think of the elements of the group ring as the translated actions of the group, up to an equivalance.

Comment: @MehmetKırdar I'm really sorry but I didn't get you. Can you please explain it again briefly?

Comment: I thought if $\Gamma$ is the geometric object at position $n=0$, then the element $\Sigma a_i g_i$ of the group ring acts on $\Gamma$ so that the resulting object is the object $\Pi g_i (\Gamma)$ at position $\Sigma a_i$. But this action is very unfaithful. I do not think that it is useful.